# C# Getting the last 10 bits of a 32 bit uint

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm looking to get the last 10 bits of a 32 Bit integer,

Essentially what I did was take a number and jam it into the first 22 bits,  I can extract that number back out quite nicely with

```
int test = Convert.ToInt32(uIActivityId >> nMethodBits); //method bits == 10 so this just pushes the last ten bits off the range
```

Where test results in the number I put in in the first place.

But now I'm stumped. So my question to you guys is. How do i get the last ten bits of a 32 bit integer?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you could push up by 22 bits and denn push down by 22 bits again.

Comment: What do you mean by "first" and "last"? Most significant and least significant would be easier to understand. Ideally, show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, too...

Comment: If you mean least significant by "last",   var last = data & 0x3ff;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First create a mask that has a 1 bit for those bits you want and a 0 bit for those you're not interested in. Then use binary `&` to keep only the relevant bits.

```
const uint mask = (1 << 10) - 1; // 0x3FF
uint last10 = input & mask;
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is another try !!

```
List<bool> BitsOfInt(int input , int bitCount)
    {
        List<bool> outArray = new BitArray (BitConverter.GetBytes(input)).OfType<bool>().ToList();
        return outArray.GetRange(outArray.Count - bitCount, bitCount);
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that the output depends on host endianness. i.e. it outputs the bits which are last in memory, and not the least significant bits.

Comment: @CodesInChaos as this question mentioned last 10 bits of a 32 Bit integer so relative answer could be last 10 bits in memory.Any way I just focused to `last` and your comment is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool[] GetLast10Bits(int input) {
        BitArray array = new BitArray(new []{input});

        List<bool> bits = new List<bool>();
        if (array.Length > 10) {
            return Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => array[i]).ToArray();
        }
        return new bool[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32("11100111101", 2);
int mask = Convert.ToInt32("1111111111", 2);
int test = Convert.ToInt32(( i&mask));
int j = Convert.ToInt32("1100111101", 2);
if (test == j)
   System.Console.Out.WriteLine("it works");
```

Comment: It is usually good to provide a bit of explanation of the code you are providing as an answer, and how it answers the question. Even if it is pretty self explanatory.